# The Rabbinical definition of the term "Halacha"

Tags: halacha-theory

This term is used everywhere in Judaism, but I have a feeling that the meaning varies greatly, for example, some Talmudic conclusions "הלכה היא" are not accepted as the ruling Halachah either by the late Gemmorah, or by the Rishonim (<sup>examples needed</sup>).

Did Poskim ever try to define this term and its applications?

Comment: I feel like the line you label as “examples needed” is pretty critical to the premise of your question...

Comment: הלכה היא= הלכה למשה מסיני

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=388